# Is every sequence bounded by a sequence which can be represented in closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Let $X$ be the set of $\mathbb{R}$-valued sequences, i.e. $X := \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}=\{f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}\}$, and let $S$ the set of sequences which can be expressed in closed form, i.e.:
$$
S:= \{f \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \space | \space f \text{ is in closed form}\} \subseteq X
$$
Now since "closed form" is not well-defined: I basically mean the usual stuff. That is: [$f$ is in closed form if there is a mathematical expression that can be evaluated in a finite number of operations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) The allowed symbols in the expression are: constants, variables and applications of $!$ (factorial), $\exp, \ln$, the trigonometric and hyperbolic functions with their inverses, $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor, \lceil \cdot \rceil, [\cdot]$.

For example, $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\in S$ if $\displaystyle a_k = e^{(k!)^2\cdot \sin\left(\binom{2k}{k}\right)}$.

Now we have $S \subset X$, i.e. there are sequences which cannot be represented in closed form.

However, does at least the following statement hold?
$$
\forall f \in X: \exists g \in S: f \leq g
$$
(i.e. every sequence is bounded by a sequence which can be expressed in closed form)

Comment: How about $a_1=3$, $a_{n+1}=a_n!$ ?

Comment: Since you admit [arbitrary real] constants in the expressions deemed "closed-form", and there are continuum-many reals, there are at least so many sequences in $S$ (not that this makes difficulty in providing an answer).

Comment: @JohnBentin oh...you are absolutely right. I'll correct that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your definition of closed form is equivalent to the primitive recursive functions.  The Ackermann function eventually overtakes every primitive recursive function, so the answer is that no function in $S$ dominates it.

In particular, probably the fastest growing type of function in your library is $n^{n^{n^n}}$ for some finite height of the tower.  Ackermann uses $2$'s instead of $n$'s, but makes the height increase without bound, so eventually it will be taller than whatever tower you pick.

Answer (score 0):

I think not. Since $S$ is countable, enumerate it as $\{s(n)\}$. Now create a sequence $t$ such that

$$
t(n)_n = 1 + \max\{ s(n)_k \ | \ k \le n \} .
$$.

This construction should work even if you allow constructions like repeated factorials $!^{n}$ as in @Mindlack 's comment.

Comment: @SmileyCraft Any number that's not the $k$th term  in $s(n)$.

Comment: You mean $t_n > s(n)_n$, not just unequal (and there's diagonalization in there too)?

Comment: I think it is useful to give $t$ explicitly, for example by $t(n)_k:=\max\{s(n)_l:1\leq l\leq k\}+1$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft Thanks. Used your suggestion.

Comment: Interestingly this also proves that you can not define a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $S$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft Now I am confused. I took the OP's word that $S$ is countable. Your argument says it's not. Now what? We will probably be told soon not to carry on a dialog in comments, but I can't chat now. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: $S$ is countable, you just can't *define* a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $S$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft Got it.